# Linked list modeling in Free Pascal

Tags: pointers, linked-list, freepascal

I am currently solving the problem of creating a [singly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list) using pointers in Free Pascal. The task:

> Write a program that reads integers from the standard input stream until the "end of file" situation occurs, after which it prints all the entered numbers TWICE in the order in which they were entered. The quantity of numbers is not known in advance, explicit restrictions on this number are prohibited.

In my program, the list is built in the wrong order. How to build the correct sequence?

```pascal
program InputStreamNumbers;
type
    itemptr = ^item;
    item = record
        data: Integer;
        next: itemptr;
    end;
var
    first, tmp: itemptr;
    n: Integer;
begin
    first := nil;            { make the list properly empty! }
    while not SeekEof do            { number reading loop }
    begin
        read(n);
        new(tmp);               { created }
        tmp^.data := n;         { fill out}
        tmp^.next := first;
        first := tmp;           { include in the list}
    end;

    tmp := first;           { go through the list from beginning to end }
    while tmp <> nil do             
    begin
        writeln(tmp^.data);
        tmp := tmp^.next;        { move to the next element}
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add nodes to the list, you create a new node named `tmp` and assign its data. That's correct. But there is an error in how you add new items to the list. The error is in

```
tmp^.next := first; // this creates the backwards linkage 
first := tmp;
```

If you can (assuming it's not against your task), add one variable more

```
last: itemptr;
```

which, as the name says, refers to the last item in the list.

The purpose is to have direct access to the end of the list, to make it easier to add items. Otherwise you would need to traverse the list from the beginning until you find the last item ( who's `item.next` is `nil`).

The list should end up like this:

```
first                                  last
  |                                      |
  v                                      v
item.next -> item.next -> item.next -> item.next = nil
    .data        .data        .data        .data
```

I leave the implementation for you to do. But if it helps, initially `first` and `last` are nil. After one item is created, both `first` and `last` point to that one item. After a second item is created, `first` still points to the first created, but last points to the second ... and so on.

Comment: Hello, Tom!
Thank you for the idea with second pointer!
I corrected the code according to your advice, but i got an error at runtime:
Runtime error 216 at $0000000000401124
  $0000000000401124
  $000000000040104C
But i can't find error according to fpc docs
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html#x189-196000D
    >216 **General Protection fault**
      >The application tried to access invalid memory space. This can be caused by 
    >several problems:
    >1.  Dereferencing a nil ptr.
    >2   Trying to access mem. which is out of bounds.  I am stuck in my code.

Comment: I'm sure you understand that I cannot possibly tell you what is wrong with code I can't see. The error message hints that you are trying to access a nil pointer or an unassigned pointer. Perhaps any `first`, `last` or `tmp` is nil.

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg, hello!
I followed your recommendation: 1. I initialized `first:=nil;`  2   `tmp:=first;`3 Before the dynamic variable  `new(first) `  i did the reading of integers `read(n)` Now there is a new problem - the program freezes when reading numbers from the file, or it stopped reading from the file

Comment: @KukuruzoFirst  We can not continue and expand the question with new problems. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. You asked a question and I answered it. If you think the answer is correct, please find the tick mark beside my answer, and click it green to indicate the question is answered. You are welcome to post new questions for new problems, accompanied with relevant code and description.